# php-redis with serializer igbinary - PHP Fatal error

Tags: serialization, redis, phpredis, objectcache, igbinary

lighttpd 1.4.69, PHP-fpm 8.2.3, debian 11, 10.5.18-MariaDB,
php-redis 5.3.7 - compression lz4
All packages are installed via apt
object cache pro wordpress plugin

php info
igbinary support - enabled igbinary version 3.2.13
redis - Available serializers php, json, igbinary
session - Registered serializer handlers php_serialize php php_binary igbinary msgpack
session.serialize_handler igbinary igbinary

`php -i | grep igbinary`
`/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,`
`igbinary`
`igbinary support => enabled`
`igbinary version => 3.2.13`
`igbinary APCu serializer ABI => 0`
`igbinary session support => yes`
`igbinary.compact_strings => On => On`
`igbinary support => yes`
`Available serializers => php, json, igbinary`
`Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary igbinary msgpack`
`session.serialize_handler => igbinary => igbinary`

If you use php as the default serializer in the configuration, then everything works very quickly. But I read that igbinary_serialize works several times faster? But when I turn on serializer igbinary, in the config, I get a critical error in wordpress.

`define( 'WP_REDIS_CONFIG', [ 'token' => '', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 6379, 'database' => 5, 'maxttl' => 3600 * 24 * 7, 'timeout' => 0.5, 'read_timeout' => 0.5, 'retry_interval' => 10, 'retries' => 3, //'serializer' => 'igbinary', 'compression' => 'lz4', 'async_flush' => true, 'client' => 'phpredis', 'split_alloptions' => true, 'shared' => true, 'prefetch' => true, 'debug' => false, 'save_commands' => false, ]); define('WP_REDIS_DISABLED', getenv('WP_REDIS_DISABLED') ?: false);`

`2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:Stack trace: 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#0 /www/free/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php(291): array_keys() 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#1 /www/free/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php(332): WP_Roles->init_roles() 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#2 /www/free/wp-includes/class-wp-roles.php(91): WP_Roles->for_site() 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#3 /www/free/wp-settings.php(542): WP_Roles->__construct() 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#4 /www/free/wp-config.php(101): require_once('...') 2023-03-08 21:10:07: (mod_fastcgi.c.449) FastCGI-stderr:#5 /www/free/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...')`

If I use the default serializer (php), everything works well. The download speed of sites is very pleasing. But if you enable serializer igbinary ('serializer' = > 'igbinary',) - Wordpress's fatal error.

I read that igbinary is much faster than php and you can increase the speed of sites.

I tried to deactivate all the wordpress plugins - it didn't help. Changing the various Redis parameters in wp-config also did not help.

Comment: Problem resolved https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary/issues/376

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.